# How to Calculate Date Discrepencies

Tags: logic

This is one of those questions that feel so simple that it's almost embarrassing to ask, but it has been something that has troubles me over some years. When calculating dates (or many other things like lines used), it never works to just minus Date B from Date A e.g 5.10.16 - 4.10.16

5-4 = 1 but in reality we have 2 days don't we. Why is this, and more importantly how would i be able to recognize things in life which have this weird +1 property? (this is more of a logic question, but i couldn't find a specialized "logic" Q&A blog, and maths is as logical as it gets right...)

Comment: But $28 - 14 = 14$, irrespective of the fact that we are counting apples or money or days.

Comment: but say, 5.10.16 - 4.10.16      ----                  

5-4 = 1 but in reality we have 2 days don't we so...

Comment: But waht you are doing is not to subtract days... you are considering the days included in the interval between the first day of the month (say the first of October ) and the last day of the month (the 31 of October ) extremes included. If so, they are 31 days. But if you want to know how many days October has, you have to subtract the last of October from the last of the preceeding month.

Comment: @JohnHon You need to think about what you want. When you make a computation, you're using numbers, not real life. It is a model. The difference of days between two dates gives you the "number of days apart the two dates", it doesn't give you the numbers of days across the date range (this would be a plus one). That's just how the model works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"+1" because you want to **include** the start day.

The thing is, when we talking about days for example: "The events starts at July 1st and Ends at July 3rd" means that the event runs at July 1st, July 2nd and July 3rd.

But when we minus things, we want to get the difference of the 2. For example: you have 5 apples, you eat 1 each days, by the end of day 5 you are eating 2 more apples than day 3. (5-3=2)

If we want to know how many apples you eat from day 3 to day 5, you have to +1 because:

At day 3, you eat 1 apple-----1

And you eat 2 more apples by the end of day 5 than day 3-------(5-3)

All together you get 1+(5-3)=3.

Hope this answered your question.